# Como eu faço para o listWidget do PyQt5 imprimir item de cores diferentes?

Tags: pyqt-5, background-color

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

Queria que o ListWidget adiciona-se um item na cor vermelha apenas na mensagem de quando ocorre a excessão. Porem no momento que o setStyleSheet e mudado para a "color: red", todo o texto que vier depois tambem irá surgir como vermelho.

O meu objetivo é que apenas a linha aonde a excessão e impressa, fique na cor vermelha. Como posso fazer isso?

```
def Conectar_IP(self):
    try:
        self.listWidget.addItem("Conectado ao IP: %s" %self.HOST)
        print("conectado: ", tnConectado)
    except:
        self.listWidget.addItem("Não foi possivel conectar a este IP")
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("font:bold; color: red")
        print("desconectado: ", tnConectado)
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: except:
            item = QListWidgetItem("Não foi possivel conectar a este IP")
            item.setBackground(QColor("red")) 
            font = self.listWidget.font()
            font.setBold(True) 
            item.setFont(font) 
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido da seguinte forma...

```
except:
            item = QListWidgetItem("Não foi possivel conectar a este IP")
            item.setBackground(QColor("red")) 
            font = self.listWidget.font()
            font.setBold(True) 
            item.setFont(font) 
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```